How to calculate calculated field and the non-calculated field in Quicksight
I’m hitting problem that can not calculate calculated field and non-calculated field.

I want to calculate cpa of advertisement.

So i made the below formula.


{advertisement_budget} / countIf({id[user]}, {utm_source} = “advertisement”)


But quicksight can not combine calculated field and non-calculated field.

How can i solve this problem?

I solved my issue.
{advertisement_budget} / sumOver(ifelse({utm_source} = 'advertisement', 1, 0),[{Date Month}],PRE_AGG)
